# Rails Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

newb here. I'm trying to perform a transaction when an order and relationship are  created and saved. Almost like if you had to pay to follow somebody. When the order is saved the relationship is created and saved.

```
def create
@order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order]) 
@order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
if @order.save
  if @order.purchase

  respond_to do |format|
    Order.transaction do
      begin
          @order.cart.line_items.all.each do |item|
          current_user.person_relationships.build(:owned_id => item.person_id)
          end
        end
        format.html {redirect_to root_path, :flash => {:success => "Transaction Success" } }
        format.xml{render xml: root_path}

      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        format.html {render :action => "failure" }
        format.xml {render :action => "failure"}

        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem comes in when the order is created. It's as if the method just skips over the item block and the order is created but no person_relationships are created. Links to where the answers might be are greatly appreciated too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the models too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you are just building the relationships but not saving them:

```
 current_user.person_relationships.build(:owned_id => item.person_id)
```

should probably be

```
 current_user.person_relationships.create(:owned_id => item.person_id)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! Side note: whats the difference between build and create?

Comment: `build` just makes a new object in memory, whereas `create` first calls `build` and then immediately calls `save` which stores the object in the database

Answer (score 0):

If it's skipping over the items, you probably have no line_items for that cart?  Check the logs for the queries rails is making and the data that comes back.